# How to serialize an object which contains two dicts and a list?

Tags: python

```
class KB(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.patterns = defaultdict(list)

        self.features = []

        self.meta_info = {}

        self._initialize()
```

I have a KB class which will be initialized through reading in a number of json files. The json files' content will be populated into the 'patterns', 'features', 'meta_info'. There are a large number of json files to be read in initializing the KB object, so it takes a quite while to do that. I want to use pickle to serialize the KB object. What's the right way to do that? One way I think is to pickle the three individually:

```
self.patterns
self.features
self.meta_info
```

Then in initializing the KB, I can unpickle the three. But is there a way to pickle the whole KB instead of the 3 variables? This is the first time I use the 'pickle' feature.

Comment: You can just pickle the KB object. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: How to do that to pickle the whole?

Comment: The same way you pickle any object, `pickle.dump(obj, file)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I pickled the whole KB object, and the file is 480MB. But it takes 15 seconds to unpickle when using the load() function. Why is it so slow to read in back? 480MB isn't a big size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, you can pickle instances of most classes.
The way to do it is the same as pickling anything else. `pickle.dump`

```
import pickle
path = path/to/filename.p
a = KB()
pickle.dump(a, open(path,"wb"))
```

or a sequence of them like this:

```
kblist = []
for _ in range(1000):
    kb = KB()
    kblist.append(kb)    
pickle.dump(kblist, open(path, "wb"))
```

To load the pickled data, you must load them into a module where the class that defines them can be found.

```
kbs = pickle.load(open(path,"rb"))
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'KB' on <module '__main__' from '/Users/cong/tests/random_test.py'>

Comment: I did something like you did, but I got this error. what might be the reason?

Comment: I had to import the KB symbol right before I call it. It's solved. My pickled file size is 480MB. Is there a way I make it smaller?

Comment: It takes 15 minutes to unpickle the 480MB file. Why does it take so long?

Comment: I wonder what's true. The 15 minutes they claimed here or the 15 seconds they claimed under the question.

Comment: @KellyBundy, actually it's 15 seconds. Is that normal? my typo. I want it to be faster. If it is 15 seconds, I would rather not pickle it. Just read the original json is almost the same speed.

Comment: @marlon  That is typically what I end up doing also.  the difference in performance is negligible and json has the benefit of being human readable.  json is typically better on storage size as and is has more compression potential too.